# Using nth-last-child(odd) and (even) to add css to an image

Tags: css, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I have a section in the wordpress page that has 2 rows, 1st row layout is text | image and 2nd row layout is text | image.  I am using ACF to get the content and I have this working using nth-last-of-type(even) and nth-last-of-type(odd) to get the two rows have the content reversed.  My problem is that the image in the row needs to have the corner cut off and this also needs to be reversed (cut left for top row and cut right for second row)

This is how it should look:
http://melindcooper.com/image1.jpg

I have the cut corner working but it is cutting the image in same place for both top and bottom image:

http://melindcooper.com/image2.jpg

Here is my code:

```
     <?php
     $posts = get_posts(array(
 'posts_per_page'   => -1,
 'post_type'        => 'leaders',
 'orderby' => 'menu_order',
 'order' => 'ASC',
 'meta_key'     => 'show_on_home_page',
 'meta_value'   => 'yes'
 ));
      if( $posts ): ?>
      <?php foreach( $posts as $post ):
     setup_postdata( $post );

   <div class="zone5" style="background-color:#ccc; margin-bottom: 20px;">
<div style="width: 50%;">
    <p class="Stitle"><?php the_field('first_name'); ?> <?php the_field('last_name'); ?></p>
    <p class="staff"><?php the_field('title'); ?></p>
    <p class="staff"><?php the_field('bio'); ?></p>
</div>
<div style="width: 50%;" class="cutCorner">
    <img src="<?php the_field('photo'); ?>" />
</div>
</div>
 <?php endforeach; ?>
 <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
 <?php endif; ?>
```

Here is my css:

```
.zone5:nth-last-of-type(odd) {
  display: -webkit-flex; /* Safari */
  -webkit-flex-direction: row-reverse; /* Safari 6.1+ */
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row-reverse; 
  }

 .zone5:nth-last-of-type(even) {
  display: -webkit-flex; /* Safari */
  -webkit-flex-direction: row; /* Safari 6.1+ */
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row; 
  }

 .cutCorner {
   position:relative; 
   display: inline-block;
   }

  .cutCorner img {
    display:block;
   }
  .cutCorner:after {
  position:absolute; left:-2px; top:-2px; content:'';
  border-top: 400px solid #ccc;
  border-right: 250px solid transparent;
  }
```

This is the css that I need to use for the second row image:

```
//Bottom Image
 .cutCorner::after {
  position: absolute;
  right: -2px;
  top: -2px;
  content: '';
  border-top: 400px solid #ccc;
  border-left: 250px solid transparent;
  }
```

How can change the bottom image css using the nth-last-of-type?  Any help would be appreciated!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Re-written your code now you will have `lastitem` class on last zone5 div and `lastcorner` class on last corner div.

you can target these classes separately

I have tested this code and it works for the last item

```
<?php

$lastItem = '';
$lastCorner = '';

$posts = new WP_Query(array(
  'posts_per_page'   => -1,
  'post_type'        => 'leaders',
  'orderby' => 'menu_order',
  'order' => 'ASC',
  'meta_key'     => 'show_on_home_page',
  'meta_value'   => 'yes'
  ));

if ( $posts->have_posts() ) : while ( $posts->have_posts() ) : $posts->the_post();

if ($posts->current_post +1 == $posts->post_count) { 
  $lastItem = 'lastitem';
  $lastCorner = 'lastcorner';
}

?>
  <div class="zone5 <?php echo $lastItem; ?>" style="background-color:#ccc; margin-bottom: 20px;">
    <div style="width: 50%;">
      <p class="Stitle"><?php the_field('first_name'); ?> <?php the_field('last_name'); ?></p>
      <p class="staff"><?php the_field('title'); ?></p>
      <p class="staff"><?php the_field('bio'); ?></p>
    </div>
    <div style="width: 50%;" class="cutCorner <?php echo $lastCorner; ?>">
      <img src="<?php the_field('photo'); ?>" />
    </div>
  </div>
<?php endwhile; endif; wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```

Comment: That is where I am stuck, how do I format the css??   .zone5:last-of-type .cutCorner:after does not work

Comment: Ohhhh then you have to add some logic in PHP to include a different class for last item for both zone and corner and then you can simply add css to it.

Comment: Replace it with wp_query and use something life `if ($wp_query->current_post +1 == $wp_query->post_count) {
    // this is the last post
}`

Comment: You can set an empty variable out side loop like `$item=''` and then within if statement add `$item = 'lastitem';` and then add `echo $item` in your div